# iOS - can't get rid of keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have a text field for a user to enter a string, then another text field that when clicked shows a view that slides up with a date picker inside it.

If the user clicks on the first text field and enters a string using the keyboard and then hits the return button on the keyboard the keyboard goes away. But if they click on the date text field after entering a string in the first text field then the keyboard stays on the screen.

I have tried this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateField;

....

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return(![textField isEqual:self.dateField]);
}
```

It doesn't work. 
I also tried this (this is triggered on begin editing when user clicks on dateField):

```
- (IBAction)dateTextFieldClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and then this:

```
- (IBAction)dateTextFieldClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

and neither of these works either. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Should I just give up or is there some way that will work?

Comment: Its a little bit confusing when your keyboard is not dismissing. Can you give a screenshot for more clarification? @Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Try This ..

```
- (IBAction)dateTextFieldClicked:(id)sender {
[self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.view endEditing:YES]; }
```

Comment: @ManuelManningtonTheThird have you added uitextfielddelegate in your interface & set delegates for your both textfields  ?

Comment: @ManuelManningtonTheThird then why dont you try delegate methods ?
you can use delegate methods like i mentioned below :

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField== nameField) {
        [self.dateField resignFirstResponder];
    }
else if (textField== dateField){
 [self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 [self.nameTextField addTarget:self action:selector@(nameFieldClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd]
```

And correct the parameter in your `dataTextFieldClicked()` as

```
 - (IBAction)dateTextFieldClicked:(UITextField *)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];    
}
```

I just be an iOS Developer when Apple launched `Swift`, which means the codes I wrote above maybe have some syntax error, but without logical error.

I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: I translated it into objective-c properly and it doesn't work. So it would be 
[self.nameTextField addTarget:self action:selector@(nameFieldClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
 - (IBAction)dateTextFieldClicked:(id)sender {
    UITextField *name = (UITextField *)sender;
    [name resignFirstResponder];    
}

Comment: Correct your `dataTextFieldClicked()` like `[sender resignFirstResponder]`

Comment: I used this method block to get `UITextField` out of the screen when I finished tying in Swift. The difference is I set the UI objects in the `Storyboard` with `Send Events` in the `Connection Inspector` instead of `addTarget( )`.

Comment: If you used `Storyboard`, you can connect `UITextField`'s `Editing Did End` to the `dataTextFieldClicked()`. And `- (IBAction)dataTextFieldClicked()`'s return value should be `void`, like `- (void)dataTextFieldClicked()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way, I had the same problem. Take the dateField as a UIButton, not as UITextField. In the Button action set this as follows:

```
- (IBAction)Date_set:(id)sender
 {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self YourDatePickerset];
}
```

Set the title of the button when DatePicker value changed like this

```
- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd LLL yyyy"]; // Date formater
    NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:[myPicker date]]; // Convert date to string
    NSLog(@"date :%@",date);
    [dob_btn setTitle:date forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this snippet and let me tell the result

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

make sure delegate is set to self for all textfields

Try this also

**EDIT**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[dateField resignFirstResponder];    
[nameField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: ok just resign for both textfields in touch began method....(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [dateField resignFirstResponder];    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
}